# Having trouble clicking .mat-simple-snackbar-action using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-material2

I am using angular 4 with angular material 2.0.0-beta.8.  I'm using the snackbar with an action.  I checked the snackbar source and it looks like this:

```
<button
  class="mat-simple-snackbar-action"
  *ngIf="hasAction"
  (click)="action()">{{data.action}}</button>
```

In my protractor test I first do something that triggers the snackbar.  Then I run this code to click on the action button on the snackbar:

```
const submit = element(by.css('.mat-simple-snackbar-action'));
submit.click();
```

I get this error

```
Failed: element not visible
    (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15
063 x86_64)
```

Any one encountered this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('.mat-simple-snackbar-action')).getWebElement());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had to add a wait for it to show up:

```
const submit = element(by.css('.mat-simple-snackbar-action'));
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(submit), 10000);
submit.click();
```